# why stll need to use Serializable attribute when the type already implements ISerializable?

Tags: c#, .net

I know `[Serializable]` marks a type to be serializable and `ISerializable` makes you can do custom serialization/deserialization by implementing `GetObjectData`, so you can see code like this below:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyType : ISerializable {
   ...
   void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) { ... }
}
```

My question is, when a type implements `ISerializable`, it implicitly indicates this type is "serializable", because the logic is, if you can have control over doing a thing as you wish, then you are "capable" to do this thing, so I think it isn't it better to omit `[Serializable]` when a type implements `ISerializable` ?

Comment: More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2237), and ultimately [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=serializable+vs+iserializable).

Comment: Side note, in 2021 you should try to avoid both. Don't use it in new code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes omit it!
With ISerializable you can define custom sterilizing behavior through the GetObjectData  override.
Using the attribute is better for single properties on an fields.
Here's a more detailed example of each use this example of a custom serialization here on StackOverflow

Comment: but I can't omit the attribute even though I did implement the ISerializable interface, an exception will be thrown

Comment: whats throwing the exception?

Comment: if I don't use `[Serializable]`, there will be `SerializationException` thrown, saying the type is not marked as serializable even though I do implement `ISerializable`

Comment: hmm not sure them